# In quantum mechanics how the expression of average value of an observable is derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, observables

In Dirac's Principles of QM following is stated:

$$
\langle x | A + B | x \rangle = \langle x | A | x \rangle + \langle x | B |x \rangle
$$

but

$$
\langle x | AB | x \rangle \ne  \langle x | A | x \rangle \langle x | B | x \rangle
$$

and so $\langle x|A|x \rangle$ is not exact but average value of observable A otherwise in second relation both sides would have to be equal.
I don't understand the second relation. Shouldn't both side be equal like this,
$\langle x|AB|x \rangle = \langle x|A(B|x \rangle) = b \langle x|A|x \rangle = ba \langle x|x \rangle = ba = \langle x|A|x \rangle \langle x|B|x \rangle$ , where $a$ and $b$ are corresponding eigenvalues. What is wrong here?

Edit: It is embarrassing. I indeed was thinking $|x\rangle$ was eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$ out of sleep deprivation I suppose which I only realised this morning. So anyway I am going to ask moderator to delete this question.

Comment: Your line $\langle x | A (B | x \rangle) = b \langle x | A | x \rangle$ is making the assumption that $B | x \rangle = b | x \rangle$, or that $| x \rangle$ is an eigenvector of $B$. This is not the case in general.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I could help you with your confusion. If we consider two hermitian operators (just ordinary QM) $A,B$ and regard
$$<v|AB|v>$$
you could run into several scenarios.

1. $|v>$ is eigenstate for operator $A$ (with eigenvalue $a$) and operator $B$ (with eigenvalue $b$). Then your argumentation is correct.
   $<v|AB|v>=ab<v|v>=<v|A|v><v|B|v>$
2. If $|v>$ is not eigenstate to one of those operators (or both) then $<v|AB|v>=<v|A|v><v|B|v>$ does no longer hold in general.
   We could consider one counter expamle:
   $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
   $$B = A$$
   $$AB = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
   $$|v> = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
   Then :
   $$<v|AB|v>=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=1$$
   But :
   $$<v|A|v>=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=0$$

In fact, this is very important to realise that the operators are not allways diagonal.

Comment: I would just clarify that it is assumed in part 1 of this answer that $\langle v|v\rangle=1$. This is true for a physical wave function, but it is impossible to normalize position eigenvectors like $|x\rangle$ in this way (they have to be normalized to the dirac delta function). Otherwise, this is a good answer!

Answer (score 2):

It is generally NOT true that $B|x\rangle=b|x\rangle$. This is only true if $|x\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $B$. However, there is another flaw in your reasoning. Even if $|x\rangle$ is an eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$ (as you assumed), it is NOT true that $\langle x| x\rangle=1$ (I assume $|x\rangle$ represents an eigenvector of the position operator $X$). Position eigenvectors are not normalizable in the usual sense. They are normalized to the dirac delta function such that $\langle y|x\rangle=\delta(y-x)$, which means $\langle x|x \rangle=\delta(0)$ in infinite.